# IPC between python app and injected DLL

Tags: python, dll, ipc, code-injection

Hello stack overflow: Sometimes reader, first time poster.

**Background:**

Windows box running XP SP3, soon to be upgraded to Windows Seven (MSDNAA <3)

I have an injected DLL which gets cycles by hooking a function that is called thousands of times a second.

I would like to communicate/control this DLL via a python app. Basically, the DLL does the work, the python app supplies the brains/decision making.

My game plan for doing this, is I would have a counter and an if statement in the DLL. Each time the hooked function is called, counter++ and then jump back to the original function until something like if ( counter == 250 ) { // dostuff(); }. My though behind this it will allow the target app to run mostly unimpeded, but will still let me do interesting things.

**Problem:**

I'm at an utter loss on which IPC method I should use to do the communication. We have sockets, shared memory, pipes, filemapping(?), RPC, and other (seemingly) esoteric stuff like writing to the clipboard.

I've NEVER implemented any kind of IPC beyond toy examples.

I'm fairly sure I need something that:

- Can handle talking back and forth between python and a DLL
- Doesn't block/wait
- Can check for waiting data, and continue if there isn't any
- If locks are involved, can continue instead of waiting
- Doesn't cost lots of time to read/write too

Help? Thank you for your time, I hope I've provided enough general information and not broken any accepted conventions.

I would like to add that the related questions box is very cool, and I did peruse it before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sockets. Your demands are essentially a requirement of asynchronous operating; Python has [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) module for asynchronous IO on sockets. At the same time, it doesn't look like Python's stdlib can asynchronously handle other IPC things, so I'd not recommend using them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about realtime, then you can use the file system for communication: a log file for the DLL's output, and a config file that is read every now and then to change the DLLs behavior.

Comment: Using a log file is *not* an IPC at all.

Comment: @ulidtko The file system is the oldest and most reliable form of IPC synchronization. That's why the POSIX standard has the same API for all forms of IPC. Since the OS **must** manage consistency and synchronization in file system operations (or not be called an OS), the file system is the easiest implementation of IPC to use for non-OS programs. Try `ls /var/run/*.pid` the next time you have access to a *nix system.

Comment: Printing is even more old and reliable form of... storing information on paper. OS **must** manage consistency of what would be printed, and any human can manage all needed synchronization itself. Why won't you try printing a "Hello world!" on paper, and then scanning and OCR-ing it to control your program? Sorry, but your comment isn't just an argument. Printers should print documents, filesystems should store files, shmem-pipes-sockets should provide the ways to do IPC.